# What is the better way to make consecutive FK relations cosistent in database?

Tags: django, database

In my django project, I have several models with consecutive relations between them. Let's say

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

At the same time, it is important for me to make the relations consistent, i.e. the album of model Song should have its FR related to the artist field.

Should I use come kind of constraint for a database, or it should be done with serialization logic?

I tried to find any related examples in django documentation

Comment: Why do you have a `ForeignKey` to `Artist` in the first place if you can derive it from the `album`?

Answer (score 0):

Given I understand it correctly, you *don't* need a `ForeignKey` from `Song` to `Artist`. Indeed, you can derive it through the `Album`, so:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Song(models.Model):
    # no artist field
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

    @property
    def artist(self):
        return self.album.artist
```

as a result, this is guaranteed to have consistency, since we don't store it separately.

In case we know we will need to determine this for a `QuerySet` of `Song`s, we can already load the related `album` and `artist` with:

```
Song.objects.select_related('album', 'album__artist')
```

where we fetch the related `Album` and `Artist` all in the same query.